# Python: Prefixing variable names to identify destination type

Tags: python, variables, scrapy, pipeline

I've started writing [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) projects (web scraping spiders). Scrapy uses pipelines to process items after scraping, which I will use to convert scraped strings into their destination types before writing them into a database with sqlalchemy.

Is it conventional to prefix variable names with a code to identify what those variables are destined to become ?

For example, I'd prefix the item keys with "date_" for dates, "str_" for strings, "fl_" for float. And then, I'd process them like so:

```
import re, datetime

item = {'fl_quantity':'23.04','fl_amount':'425.00 USD','date_invoice':'2014-05-28','date_period':'N/A'}

for key in item:
    if key.startswith("date_"):
        try:
            item[key] = datetime.datetime.strptime(item[key],"%Y-%m-%d").date()
        except:
            item[key] = None
    elif key.startswith("fl_"):
        try:
            item[key] = float(re.search("\d+(\.\d+)?",item[key]).group(0))
        except:
            item[key] = None

>>>print item
{'fl_amount': 425.0, 'fl_quantity': 23.04, 'date_period': None, 'date_invoice': datetime.date(2014, 5, 28)}
```

Is this considered to be good practice or not ? Are there any better ways to achieve this goal ?

Comment: Putting prefixe (or suffixe) on your variable/class/function/whatever is always a good practice in a big project if everybody in the project respect the same conventions. It's like in anyother langage.
But persisting on db (or everywhere) with type based on the variable name is not a very good practice for me. What do you do if the variable's name is not correct ? What do you do if you use another program to complete your db ? (the python program has to be updated). You should consider creating model objects containing its value and its own type (and maybe other infos)

Comment: I think it is better to keep the name case by case basis and not generalise. Because if the variable name is incorrect and someone else reads the code, they might presume the variable already of particular type. However, while retrieving or inserting data in database you can keep the local variables (such as inside a function ) with their type such as `invoicedate`. Its also better to use two or three words meaningful for the variable rather than just a single. for ex: rather than just "quantity" use "itemquantity", "productquantity", etc.

Comment: Also I do not like underscores in variable names, as it makes me feel I am typing smooth.

Comment: @daa [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) disagrees with you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I use models to describe tables and such, and since I use PostgreSQL, I find it easier to use lowercase underscores, so I don't have to manually rename all of them in the declaration.